# Bloated PowerPoint file

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-powerpoint, charts

I am tearing my hair out over a PowerPoint file that has suddenly bloated from 8 MB to 64 MB, with no new slides having been added. A series of charts have simply been renewed or newly added. They are embedded, I guess.

I have started trying making them into images, but having spent a long time aligning and adjusting everything to perfection, this is far from ideal, plus they are slightly squashed here and there.

I have also broken all links for charts in the file. Is there not a simple way to de-embed, or get rid of all the data attached to these charts, or to do something to de-bloat this file...?

Answer (score 2):

You can try compressing the images, if there are uncompressed images within the document.

From [here](http://www.ethos3.com/tech-tips/how-to-compress-powerpoint-presentations/)

> **Step 1:** Right-click on any image throughout the deck and select,
>   ‘Format Picture’ on the menu.
>
> **Step 2:** Locate and click the ‘Picture’ tab and select ‘Compress’.
>
> **Step 3:** Either ‘Apply’ the compression to selected pictures, or to all
>   pictures in the document.
>
> **Step 4:** Locate and click the ‘Change resolution’ tab and select either
>   web/screen or print...
>
> **Step 5:** Under ‘options’, find the ‘Compress pictures’ box and the
>   ‘delete cropped areas’ box. Place a checkmark in each and select ‘ok’.

[image]

Comment: "A series of charts have simply been renewed or newly added. They are embedded, I guess." If they've been added from e.g. Excel and embedded, you've got a complete copy of the original Excel workbook in your PPT file. A complete copy for each chart.  As a test, make a copy of the presentation file, then ungroup each of the newly added charts, then save the presentation again.  Smaller now?